# How can I show a Panel on a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, panel, richtextbox

There is a `Button` that changes its position vertically depending on which line the marker is installed in the `RichTextBox`. It is necessary that when I click on the `Button` the `Panel` (or `UserControl`, maybe it's better) appeared opposite the `Button` to the full width of the `RichTextBox`.

`Panel` should be located on the `RichTextBox`. That is, if the initial size of the form `(500, 500)` and this `Panel` is displayed from the edge to the edge of the `RichTextBox`, when the user changes the frame size to `(500; 1000)` and again presses the `Panel` display, this `Panel` should stretch and everything is also displayed on the `RichTextBox`. Below is the code for displaying the `Button` vertically and an animated GIF example of what I need.

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pos = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);

    Point locationOnForm = panel1.FindForm()
            .PointToClient(panel1.Parent.PointToScreen(panel1.Location));

    Point newLocation = new Point(locationOnForm.X - 10, pos.Y + locationOnForm.Y - 13);

    button1.Location = newLocation;
}
```

[image: Example GIF]

Comment: Maybe you could try something with [control layering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984382(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Comment: You can overlay the uc, positioning it similarily like you place the button. Where exactly is the problem? (Note that it will overlay the RTB, ie it will cover part of the Text..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onClick method you could position the panel next to it?

```
    private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPanel.Location = new Point(MyButton.Location.X + MyButton.Width, MyButton.Location.Y);
        MyPanel.Visible = true;
    }
```

And if you want it to be the same height as the button, add this line inside the method.

```
MyPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(MyPanel.Width, MyButton.Height);
```

And for stretching it you can use your forms SizeChnged event

```
    private void MyForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           MyPanel.Width - MyButton.width + 5;
        }
```